# Fetch expiry date from PKCS12 certificate in iOS

Tags: iphone, security, openssl

How to fetch the expiry date from PKCS12 certificate using iOS security framework?
Alternately can I use openssl? if yes, please point me towards relevant API's

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question!  If I were doing this coding, I would first try to think of a solution using Keychain Services.

First, you'd need to fetch the keychain item.  Say, via [`SecItemCopyMatching()'](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/SecItemCopyMatching).

This returns a reference to the found items.  Preferably a `SecCertificateRef` (which is described more in detail in Apple's [Keychain Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/keychainservices/Reference/reference.html) guide).

I don't see an easy way to explicitly fetch the metadata (or expiration date) from a `SecCertificateRef` off the top of my head.  [There's a code snippet I found on books.google.com](http://books.google.com/books?id=OG6_lsfffjkC&lpg=PA218&ots=osRjqNWp6J&dq=SecCertificateRef%20metadata&pg=PA218#v=onepage&q=SecCertificateRef%20metadata&f=false) from "IOS 5 Programming Pushing the Limits: Developing Extraordinary Mobile Apps" called "Checking Certificate Validity" (pages 218 & 219 -- I've linked it for you) which basically checks to see if a certificate allows usage based on matching keys (in their example, it's the subject or domain name; for you, it would be the expiration date).  Their technique may help you out.

As for using OpenSSL, [I found an answer where you can come up with the expiration date from the command line using the openssl tool](http://www.brandonhutchinson.com/When_does_my_certificate_expire%3F.html).  If you can get a handle to your certificate, I'm pretty certain this can be done programmatically as well.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Both are helpful.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. Both are helpful. 

I couldn't use the first approach, as the certificate is not saved in key chain.  I am saving the certificate in file.

I went ahead with the openssl, it is simple and straight forward. 

Steps:
1) Obtain the PKCS12 using d2i_PKCS12_fp API.
2) Parse and fetch the x509 using PKCS12_parse API.
3) Finally get the expiry date from x509 using X509_get_notAfter.

Not sure why apple trimmed SecGetResult and other useful API's in iOS.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but my guess is that they need to handle other kinds of certificates besides PKCS12, so the code Apple provides needs to be generic enough as possible to be able to handle as many kinds of certificates as possible.